# How to pass variable between jenkins pipeline from shell script conditional result

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

in the first stage, i've shell script to check directory in the remote server and the results will be sent to the next stage. I have tried the following way but it seems the variable is not read in the execute stage, is there another proper way?

```
pipeline {
    agent any
        stages 
        {
            stage("validate")
            {
                steps
                {
                   sh '''
                   dir_path="/home/servicenamedir"
                   ssh username@host bash -c "'
                   if [ -d "$dir" ] 
                     then 
                       checkdir="true" 
                   else 
                       checkdir="false" 
                   fi
                   '"
                   '''
                }
            }
            stage("execute")
            {
                steps
                {
                  sh '''
                        if [ "$checkdir" == "true" ] 
                            then 
                                 echo "directory already exist, please double check";
                                 exit;
                        elif [ "$checkdir" == "false" ]
                            then
                                 echo "execute ./install-service.sh" 
                        fi
                        '''
                } 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. create variable
   def var
2. use options returnStdout: true. And parse output
   Def var = sh ( script " ls -la", returnStdout: true).split("\n")
3. use var in stage 'execute'
   If (var[0] =="true"){...} else {...}

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/

Comment: but i'm wondering how to put ssh username@host bash -c "' inside `Def var = sh ( script " ssh command here", returnStdout: true).split("\n")`

Comment: May be linux env  help you. export VAR=value